# Opening SQL Sever Management Studio and Databases

Tags: boot, sql

Is there a way when opening SQL Server Management Studio to also open databases along with it. For instance, I usually work on a minimum of 6 databases during an usual day, and if I could get the SQL Server Management Studio to automatically open those database, so the only thing I need do is select which one I'm going to use, that would be great.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are some command line arguments you can use to start SQL Server Management Studio and connect to a specific database directly, as pointed out on [this blog post](http://www.pinaldave.com/bimg/ssmsshortcut.jpg).

To see the command line options, type `ssms /?` at the command prompt.

[image]

So you could save one command line in a shortcut or batch file to quick connect to a database. To avoid storing password in plain text, logging with the -E option to use Windows Authentication is advisable.

Unfortunately each command line spawns a new instance, at least on SQL Server 2008 R2 I tested with. I have not found a way to open multiple connections on the same SQL Server Management Studio window.

Hopefully, it can still help you save some time.

Comment: @Frank You're welcome. Please mark as answered if you are ready to.